# How to write this Regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex

So i have a string in input that represent a format for a duration. This format can be of various type like : "hh:mm:ss" or "sssss" or ""hhmmss" etc...

My goal is to understand if this string, inserted by the user is a valid format. What i did until now :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]");
input = rgx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

At this point i have a string that should be in this format "hhmmss" or "sssss" or "mmss". I need to check if the user inserted some typo by mistake, doing a Regex.Match using this list of valid blocks

```
List<string> entry = new List<string> { 
  "h", "hh", "hhh", "hhhh", 
  "m", "mm", "mmm", "mmmm", "mmmmm", 
  "s", "ss", "sss", "ssss", "sssss" };
```

how can i do that?

EDIT: I'll try to explain some points. First of all, in this phase of my tool, i just need to check if the input from the user is valid. With valid, i mean that, any format that the user will enter (with separator or not), it is composed by at least the block of second. I am supossing that the user won't do anything like `input = hsssmhhmms` cause it won't have any sense. The only thing i'll concede is a typo (for instance it press "g" instead of "h"). Of course the problem it's still hard, since this blocks of data can be wrapped in a multidute of forms. That is why i did that first step, to work on a compact block.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you not know how to do alternative values in a check? (ie `(a|b)`), do you not know how to find one or more matches of a group? Something else? What separators are allowed? Is there a limit to the number of blocks you can have?

Comment: @AlexK.: I don't think that is what the OP wants. I believe the input can be a combination of the items in that list, possibly with a `:` separator.

Comment: I get the feeling you try to implement something very broad... After checking validity, what will you do next with input?

Comment: Personally I don't think RegEx is the best thing for this job. I'd split the string into parts and then check each part to see if it is valid. This way you can also more easily have logic like "you can only have one group with m in it" (I'm assuming that `m:mm:mmm` probably isn't valid).

Comment: @Chris wouldn't necessarily agree with the unique group idea... take `"ddd, d MMM yyyy"` as a pattern where week-day is followed by day-of-month.

Comment: @grek40: True, though I would imagine that there are some that you wouldn't expect to be repeated. Though I guess it might be that as long as it is valid then it doesn't much matter if it is nonsense. Whcih makes me then wonder if a try/catch with an attempt to use it as a format string might not be the best way to validate...

Comment: You really need to define what is valid first. According to what you say string like "h:h:h:h:h,h,m.m.m.m.h.h.m.m;h;m;h;m" will be valid. This would be changed to "hhhhhhmmmmhhmmhmhm" and this string contains only valid parts (from entry list)

Comment: I'm trying to build a tool that is as general as possible. Consider all the possible income is very difficult and can bring to some very ankward solution. Plus i am a beginner of Regex (never used before) and i was told to use this tool to achieve my goal. So what @PablonotPicasso said can happen, but in this case, if a user is so dumb to put something like that in input it's not my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be sure that it is ordered? (h->m->s)
Then it's:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, "^([h]{0,4})[:]?([m]{0,5})[:]?([s]{0,5})$");
if (match.Success)
{
    string hours = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string mins = match.Groups[2].Value;
    string secs = match.Groups[3].Value;
}
```

If not:

```
var match = Regex.Match(tbName.Text, "^([h]{0,4}|[m]{0,5}|[s]{0,5})[:]?([h]{0,4}|[m]{0,5}|[s]{0,5})[:]?([h]{0,4}|[m]{0,5}|[s]{0,5})$");
if (match.Success)
{
    string hours = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains('h'));
    string mins = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains('m'));
    string secs = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains('s'));
}
```

[You can test these Expressions here:](https://regex101.com/r/xVja9g/1)

**PS:**

if you replace `:` with `\W_` it will allow other non-word character (,;-_? etc.)

`?` stands for zero or one. -> you can have only one of them in between.

`*` allows zero or many non-word character. -> so you can have something like: `"hhh_-_--,.,;;mm,ssss"`

Comment: I marked your answer cause it solved my problem of understand if a format is valid. However, i want to point out that the second part of your solution, work only in the first case (i.e. order is h->m->s for sure). In the second case, the 3 string are all the same and equals to the input, while in the first case it split correctly

Comment: Thanks, for your feedback!

I don't completely get your point.

The Second regex matches any combination of h/s/m seperated by zero or one `:`:

"hhmmss"
"hh:mmss"
"ss:mmhh"
"mmhhss"
"ss"
"ss:hhh"
"hhmm"
.....

The regex splits the input into 3 groups. If input does not contain one or mor of s/m/h the the match contains empty groups.

Example:
input = "sss"
Match:
Full match: "sss"
Group 1: ""
Group 2: ""
Group 3: "sss"

Comment: yeah i get what     `tring hours = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Select(x=>x.Value).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Contains('h'));` part does. I'm pointing out that in the case that the order could not be h->m->s (i.e. your second solution) it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: As example take this case. The user write as input "mmss". The match has success, but the output string will be : hours = null , minutes = "mmss", seconds = "mmss"

Comment: Aaaah thanks! I forgott that group[0] is the full match! I'll fix that!

Comment: `.Skip(1)` fixed it!

Comment: Your Welcome! Thanks for the feedback and not instant down vote the awnser! Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just *try formatting*? If system *can* format out then `userFormat` is a correct format:

```
private static bool IsValidFormat(string userFormat) {
  // Gini pig
  TimeSpan sample = new TimeSpan(1234567);

  string escaped = string.Concat(userFormat
    .Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) || c == '%'
       ? c.ToString() 
       : "\\" + c.ToString())); // delimiters like :,;+... should be escaped

  try {
    sample.ToString(escaped);

    return true;
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
    return false; 
  } 
}

...

// is this allowed? - true
Console.WriteLine(IsValidFormat(@"hh;mm;;ss+++ffff*h"));
// is this allowed? - false
Console.WriteLine(IsValidFormat(@"zzzz"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your escaping... Your statement that "If system can format out then userFormat is a correct one" seems sensible but the string you actually test is not the one the user provided because you have potentially escaped a load of stuff? It may be that the OP will want to do some escaping but they have provided no indication of this and if escaping is needed I think it should be independent of the validation - otherwise you return true to say its valid and then have to make sure you do the escaping all over again somewhere else...

Comment: @Chris: you are quite right; a much better practice is to convert the format provided by *user*, i.e. `hh:mm:ss` to the string required by *system* `hh\:mm\:ss` *once*, and then test it, if the test passed, parse/format the actual data. However, the question states "format can be of various type like : `"hh:mm:ss"`...  if this string, inserted by the user is a *valid format*..."; since `"hh:mm:ss"` is expected to be a *valid format* I've added *escaping*.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The problem is that at the end, i need to convert the input from the user, in an int that represent the total second elapsed.  Plus @Chris, i'm not expecting a valid format for sure, or all my concerns wouldn't exist. I have to check if what the user want to insert is valid. And also, the input could apper not separated but as a single block.